# How to make auto_search using ajax jquery, php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have created auto suggest using Javascript AJAX now I want to create auto suggest using Jquery AJAX here is the code I have written using jquery AJAX

This is my indexa.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search_input").keyup(function(){
    var txt = $("#search_input").val();
    $.get("search.inc.php?search_username="+document.search_form.txt, {suggest: txt}, function(result){
        $("searchResults").html(result);
      });
   });
  });
   </script>

 </head>
  <body>

    <form id="search" name="search_form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> " method="post">

    Search For Names : <input type="text" id="search_input" name="search_text"><br/><br/>
    <!-- <input type="submit" > -->

    </form>

    <div id="searchResults"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my search.inc.php

```
  <?php

 if (isset($_GET['searched_username'])) {
   $username = $_GET['searched_username'];
 }

  if (!empty($username)) {
      if (@$db_connect=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
         if (@mysqli_select_db($db_connect,'my_databse')) {

        $query_like = "SELECT `user_name` FROM `members_data` WHERE `user_name` LIKE '%". mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,$username)."%'";
        $query_like_run = mysqli_query($db_connect,$query_like);
        $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_like_run);
        if ($query_num_rows == NULL) {
            echo 'No Result Found';
        } else {
            if ($query_num_rows == 1) {
                echo $query_num_rows ." Result found<br/><br/>";
            } else {
                echo $query_num_rows ." Results found<br/><br/>"; 
            }
            foreach ($query_like_run as $searched_members) {
                $searched_results = '<a href="anotherpage.php?searched_username='.$searched_members['user_name'].'">'.$searched_members['user_name']."</a><br/>";
                echo $searched_results;
            }
        }       
        }
   }
 }
   ?>
```

what I am doing worng . Please Help me

Comment: what you are doing wrong is posting a question without saying the problem encountered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the values from the url and change the key to `search_username`

Do the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search_input").keyup(function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $.get("search.inc.php", {searched_username: txt}, function(result){
        $("#searchResults").html(result);//don't forget the # for the id
      });
   });
  });
   </script>
```

Comment: inivascu Thank`s a lot can u tell me for what purpose $.load function is used by giving small simple example. I u don't mine please

Comment: load is shorter syntax  for $.get +html();

Comment: how can i use animation

Comment: I mean displaying with animation

Answer (score 0):

The param name is different between your indexa.php and search.inc.php files.

You should use

```
if (isset($_GET['search_username'])) { $username = $_GET['search_username']; }
```

or

```
if (isset($_GET['suggest'])) { $username = $_GET['suggest']; }
```

To get the value your wanted in search.inc.php file

or change `search.inc.php?search_username="+document.search_form.txt`

to

```
search.inc.php?searched_username="+document.search_form.txt
```